# How can I find the attribute information of User-defined types in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql

Consider I have a user-defined type as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE mytype AS
 (myvar character(1),
  myvar2 bit(10));
```

Can I use any of Postgres’s information tables in order to get the attribute information for this type:

I.e. given “mytype”, the information I want is:

- `myvar  : character(1)`
- `myvar2 : bit(10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `pg_type` table will have the `typrelid` column populated. This is an OID key for the `pg_class` table, which then is used in `pg_attribute` tables, just as with tables, views, indices etc. So sth like:

```
select attname, format_type(atttypid, atttypmod)
from pg_type
     join pg_class on pg_class.oid = pg_type.typrelid
     join pg_attribute on pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid
where typname = 'mytype'
order by attnum
```

Comment: Another option might be `information_schema.attributes`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-attributes.html

Comment: This really helps me a lot, and I spend lots of time to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to response https://stackoverflow.com/a/9195771/6178141 I'd like to add some comments.

One needs to consider a couple of things here.

1) There can be deleted attributes. Yes, one can alter an existing type and add and/or remove attributes. Deleted attributes are flagged with TRUE in `attisdropped` column, but they do take attribute number. For instance, if we execute the following statements in additon to DTL above:

```
 ALTER TYPE mytype ADD ATTRIBUTE abc double precision;
 ALTER TYPE mytype DROP ATTRIBUTE myvar2;
```

then attribute `abc` will have physical number 2 while `attnum` value will be 3.

So we need to add this condition to `WHERE` clause:

```
AND NOT attisdropped
```

2) Also need to take into account type's schema. `mytype` will work for `public` schema. If type is created in a different schema, it won't work. In this case I personally prefer more the following condition:

```
WHERE attrelid = 'myschema.mytype'::regclass
```